# Looking for a program to draw scientific sketches

Tags: draw

Does someone know a free program with which i can draw high quality figures for my scientific thesis. I want to draw similar figures like this example

[image]

Picture is from:  E. Lucon  Oscillateurs coupl ́es, d ́esordre et synchronisation - PhD thesis

Comment: I'm afraid StackOverflow is a site for programming questions, asking for software recommendations is off topic. You may want to try: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: All right, thx for the information